# Can eclipse .classpath support multiple JRE's for different environments?

Tags: eclipse, macos, ubuntu, classpath

We've been working on MacOSX with Java SE 7 (13).  Our new colleague is on Ubuntu with OpenJDK.  I've been checking .classpath into git which has been fine until our new colleague joined.  Is there some way to get .classpath to support different JRE libraries for the different users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't recall there was such a thing, but here's how I'd do it.

Create one .classpath per environment (.classpath.macos, .classpath.ubuntu, ...).  Then remove .classpath from source control, and make sure it gets ignored by your VCS (add to .gitignore for git for example).

Then developers on mac create a link

```
ln -s .classpath.macos .classpath
```

same on ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks!  That's what we're doing for now.  So I feel validated.  I'll wait a short while to see if someone knows of a different approach and if not, I'll mark yours as the best answer.

Comment: sounds good.  In the past, I've also use a custom tool that was generating the .classpath based on various parameters, including platform, config file, ...

Comment: I'm an old time command line geek.  I prefer to handle all this stuff myself from ant or other config tools that don't do arbitrary magic like eclipse.  Not an option on this particular project.